# Hover on td affect superior tr

Tags: css, hover

I made a table where the first `<tr>` has two `<td>` (the first with rowspan) and the second `<tr>` has only a `<td>`. I want that when I make hover on the `<td>` of the second `<tr>` to affect itself and the first `<td>` of the first `<tr>`.

This is similar to what I want: http://jsfiddle.net/M3Wya/

This is the code:

```
<table class="class">
    <tr><td rowspan="2">A</td><td>B</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C</td></tr>
</table>
```

If I make hover on B i want A and B to change (it works with `.class tr:hover{}`) and if I make hover on C i want A and C to change in the same way.

It's possible to make it with only CSS? I don't know how to do it (I know the sibling selector but I can't find how to use it here.

If it's not possible with CSS how could I do it with JavaScript?

This is the solution:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cGhwL

Comment: If you hover on C (second row), you want the first row to be highlighted?

Comment: No. Only A and C. Not the whole row.

Comment: The problem is there doesn't seem to be a logical reason for this, so any solution will likely not be extensible. If you want a hover on any cell to highlight only cells A & B, you could do `table.class:hover tr:first-child { background-color: #3C3228; color: #FFF; }` (and transitions, of course). [Here's a demo forked from your example](http://jsfiddle.net/M3Wya/).

Comment: You can't do that with just CSS since you can't go through the DOM in ascendant way.

Comment: @Barney This is completely logical. The idea is to highlight the "visual" row.  Since A spans two rows, it is visually part of both rows.  Hovering on a cell in either row should highlight A.

Comment: @JamesMontagne you had a comment with a solution that the OP then commented as being accepted — but both have disappeared! Re-write it as an answer?

Comment: @Danko, that is what i thaught. The only solution seems to be javascript.

Comment: @Barney I deleted it because after looking at it, it was a very non-generic solution and only worked if every first cell in a row had a rowspan.  But I guess with this specific table setup that is fine.  Link is here:  http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/table-row-hover-with-rowspan/

Comment: pure JS or are you already using Jquery ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do this with css alone.  I couldn't find a good generic javascript solution, so I created the following in jquery.  Hope it helps:

http://jsfiddle.net/UJeCt/1/

```
$("td").hover(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var $thisTr = $this.closest("tr");
    var $rows = $thisTr.parent().children();

    // add hover to call cells directly in the same tr
    $thisTr.find("td").addClass("hover");

    // add hover to any td with rowspan making it visually part of this row
    var rowIndex = $rows.index($thisTr[0]);

    $thisTr.prevAll("tr:has(td[rowspan])").each(function(){
        var index = $rows.index(this);

        $(this).find("td[rowspan]").each(function(){
            var $cell = $(this);

            if($cell.attr("rowspan") > rowIndex - index){
                 $cell.addClass("hover");   
            }
        });
    });
}, function(){
    $(".hover").removeClass("hover");
});
```

Comment: This is the solution, i would like to see it applied to my particular case. This is what I want, but i don't know exactly how to implement it. Thanks!

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cGhwL

Comment: Just change the `html` in the fiddle to your html and you will see it works without update.  http://jsfiddle.net/UJeCt/2/  In your real page, you will probably want to add a more specific selector though, something like `$(".class td").hover(function(){`

Comment: I forgot to thank you personally. It served me. Thanks also to Barney, who helped me too.

Comment: Excellent solution — I'd written a very elaborate piece of code that bound data to each cell that was 'rowspanned' on init, but this is so much terser and more performant.

Answer (score -1):

You can make us of CSS the first selector

```
table.class:hover tr:first-child { 
  /* something */
}
```